# DevOps Publish Error: EPERM operation not permitted

Tags: azure-devops

When building an artifact using Azure DevOps, "Publish artifact" task failed with error

> Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: EPERM: operation not permitted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using `A file server` option as an Artifact publish location for Publish task, make sure the Agent/Service has access to the server.

In my case, I added the agent in Administrator group to be able to do WRITE operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you use self-hosted agent, by default it runs as local NETWORK SERVICE account that doesn't have access to remote shares. So you should either:

1. Change agent's logon account. For some reason Microsoft [doesn't recommend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#run-as-a-service) to change it from Services snap-in, but rather reconfigure it from their scripts.
2. Grant to local NETWORK SERVICE account access to remote share. To do it, you need to add  computer account with your agent (i.e. "DOMAIN\ServerA$") to Share and NTFS permissions on the shared folder. See for example [here](https://serverfault.com/q/41130/440014).

Answer (score 1):

In case of an self-hosted agent, with a (local) account there is a possibility that the account that is used for the file copy action is out of date / expired.

Not the account that runs the service, but another one that is stored with the service account in the Windows Credentials manager.

The only thing I needed to do is reenter the credentials in the Windows Credential manager and redeploy the task.